# Turning incoming pixel uchar4 vector into one int value

Tags: android, bitmap, pixel, renderscript

in my renderscript file, I have the following kernel function:

```
uchar4 RS_KERNEL applyRGBProcessing(uchar4 in){


}
```

As you might you know: the parameter **uchar4 in** represents a vector with 4 values. In my case, it represent a pixel coming from a bitmap. 
How can I turn this `uchar4` into an normal `int` ?
The reason why I ask is that I want to apply the following formula within the body of that kernel function:

```
pixels[i] = (0xFF000000 & pixels[i]) | (R[(pixels[i] >> 16) & 0xFF]) | (G[(pixels[i] >> 8) & 0xFF]) | (B[pixels[i] & 0xFF]);
```

So, there we apply some shifting and ANDing operations to `pixel[i]`. But I can not replace simply the `pixel[i]` with my `in` parameter because `pixel[i]` is an `int` and `in` is of type `uchar4`.

And of course, I have to return uchar4 back. So, I have to:

- convert it into sth. appropriate
- make the shift and AND
- re-convert it back into uchar4
- return this uchar4

How could I do that?

**UPDATE:**

My solution so far(which does NOT work very well, the whole screen becomes blue):

```
uchar4 RS_KERNEL applyRGBCurve(uchar4 in){

    int red = in.r;
    int green = in.g;
    int blue = in.b;
    int alpha = in.a;

    int pixel = alpha | red | green | blue;

    uchar4 out;
    out.a = (0xFF000000 & pixel);
    out.r = R[(pixel >> 16) & 0xFF];
    out.g = G[(pixel >> 8) & 0xFF];
    out.b = B[pixel & 0xFF];

    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be necessary to convert to int and back to uchar4 - the formula you are trying to apply seems to simply interpret the int as four bytes in the order ARGB. Your input is probably stored in the order ABGR (see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config#ARGB_8888)), so you could try:

```
uchar4 RS_KERNEL applyRGBCurve(uchar4 in){

   uchar4 out;

   out.a = in.a;
   out.r = in.b;
   out.g = in.g;
   out.b = in.r;

   return out;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not what I want. I have to put those in.r, in.b and in.g values into the R, G and B arrays. What these arrays are is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57396733/method-that-processes-pixels-in-a-certain-way?noredirect=1#comment101275629_57396733